# Question on why a particular quasi-isomorphism between complexes doens't have an inverse

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories, derived-categories

My question is on the example below, taken from page 4 of http://www.math.wisc.edu/~andreic/publications/lnPoland.pdf.

I'm not familiar enough with this stuff yet to understand why the quasi-isomorphism below does not have an inverse.

I'm also caught up on the second example since I don't understand what the map $(x, y)$ means. Is that projection from the first part of the direct sum onto $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$?

I would be appreciative if anyone here could work out the details on these examples.

[image]

Comment: There are no nonzero maps from $Z/2$ to $Z$, for the first question.

Comment: The obvious one is $(f,g)$ goes to $xf+yg$, but then they are quasi-isomorphic (from the second complex to the first: $f \to (yf,-xg)$, $z\to z$).